# Locating BLOBs inside of a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2008, blob

I have a SQL Server 2008-R2 database that I am migrating it's data to a different SQL Server 2008-R2 database. The database contain over 400 tables but I need to find all tables that contain images and documents that are saved in BLOB format and put those items into a separate database (also SQL 2008-R2).

I have used the following script to locate all tables that have either a Binary, Image, Varbinary, Varchar(MAX), nVarchar(MAX):

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(c.id) as TableName,
    c.name as ColumnName, 
    c.colid As ColumnOrder,
    st.name as UserType,
    bt.name as BaseType
FROM 
    dbo.syscolumns c
    INNER JOIN dbo.systypes st ON st.xusertype = c.xusertype
    INNER JOIN dbo.systypes bt ON bt.xusertype = c.xtype
WHERE 
    OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id,'ISTABLE') = 1
    AND((st.name = 'nvarchar' AND c.length = 8000) OR
        (st.name = 'varchar' AND c.length = 8000) OR 
        (st.name in('sql_variant','varbinary','binary','image')))
ORDER BY
    OBJECT_NAME(c.id), 
    c.colid
```

But this only cuts the list in half, other than building SELECT Statements for each of these tables is there an easier way of finding BLOB files in this database?

Comment: @MarkKarm what aspect of this query doesn't find the tables/columns with BLOBs?